# Angular 2 Tutorial: Routers for Hall of Heroes compiles but not displaying content in browser

Tags: angular

I am trying to work through the Angular 2 tutorial and am getting stuck on the "Router" section.  Specifically the RouterModule in app.module.ts.

As soon as I add:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/heroes',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'heroes',
            component: HeroesComponent
        }
```

to the imports array, the content in the browser is no longer displayed.  Even after I add the routes to app.component.ts file as shown below the application only displays "Loading AppComponent content here ..." even though all files compile.

This effectively stops me in my tracks and cannot continue.  It was going fine until I add this point which means my code base is okay except the router stuff.

Is there an issue in the tutorial, perhaps something out of date?

Here is the code for app.module.ts:

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';

    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
    import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

    import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/heroes',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'heroes',
                component: HeroesComponent
            }
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent,
        HeroesComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HeroService
      ],
      bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
      ]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the code from the app.component.ts:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <nav>
                <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
            </nav>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `
    })

    export class AppComponent  {
        title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when I was doing the tutorials. I was able to resolve this by putting the following HTML base tag in the index.html. Hope this helps!

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I added this in the <head> section beneath the title and I am still having the same problem.  The issue is not resolved so I will keep trying for a solution.

Comment: Hey! Judging from the documentation found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) it seems to be best to include the tag anyways. It should be the first child in the header. I might be able to help you solve this problem, if you provide some extra information. When you open the application in Chrome, press F12 and go to the console tab, what errors do you see?